# Blazor on click method not working on .netcore 3.1 application

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, .net-core, blazor

I working on MVC project with using .Net Core 3.1. I included blazor pages.

`_Imports.razor` is created to the project folder.
Endpoints has `.MapBlazorHub` and services contains `ServerSideBlazor()`.
I added "`_framework/blazor.server.js`" and "`<base href="/">`" to the layout page.

I think some detail is missing but I have no idea.

_Imports.razor

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Monitoring
@using Monitoring.Components
```

Layout head tag

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<base href="/">
```

configure

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            });
```

configure services

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); ;
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

And I trigger the click event like this. I try debug with breakpoints, this method is never called.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success align-right" @onclick="AddMoreActionClick">Add More Action</button>

private Models.Alerts alerts = new Models.Alerts() { Server = new Models.Servers(), Actions = new List<Models.Actions>() { new Models.Actions() } };

    public void AddMoreActionClick()
    {
        alerts.Actions.Add(new Models.Actions());
    }
```

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED!!**

I carried `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` this block to bottom of body from the head tags and then works perfectly. I didnt understand how does it work. Anyway problem is solved to end of day.

```
<body>
    <div>
         blabla
    </div>
    **<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>**
</body
```

Comment: I had the same issue in my asp.net MVC project and after struggling to find the solution, the issue was that some JSInterop was failing as it was calling a js function which didn't exist, fixing that my click events started working again. Have a look if you have a similar issue?

Comment: If i understand what do you mean exactly, i checked the console error logs on the inspect mode. There two error was throwed. I cleared that errors,but there is no changes about the click event.